# HTML form not updating, when being manipulated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, i am in the midst of making a little website where you can calculate right angled triangles. Y'know, just for the fun of it.

Atm, i'm testing the real time calculation of the different html forms, however, i can't figure out why the form for cathetusB isn't updating.

Any help is appreciated!

This is how all the forms are set up: `<input type="number" step="0.01" id="someID" onkeyup=calculate();>`

[The JS code messed up when i tried to paste it in, so here's a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/x4efbe7s/)

EDIT: Added all the code to the Fiddle!

Comment: You don't have a calculate function in your JS.

Comment: Did you check my solution?

Comment: The code doing all the calculation is gonna go in the calculate() function, between getNumbers() and draw().
I'm just testing the real-time calculation aspect atm.
That's why it's a bit "messy" to look at. It's just testing.

Comment: You need to provide a reduced test case that actually demonstrates the problem. Showing us a tiny fragment of the HTML and linking to JS on a completely different website is not sufficient.

Comment: Did you debug it? trying running using F12.

Comment: @Quentin I have added all the code to the fiddle.
Sorry for being inconvenient!

Comment: Oh, that doesn't make sense..
How do i bring up the error console?
I've never really used JSFiddle before..

Comment: The error console is a feature of your browser. Most browsers make it available through F12 and various menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured JSFiddle so that the code runs in an `onload` event handler.

The functions are therefore scoped to that handler function.

They are not globals.

They are not accessible to your intrinsic event handlers.

**Configure JSFiddle to place the JS in the body instead of onload and [the code works](http://jsfiddle.net/x4efbe7s/1/).**

[image: JSFiddle configuration]

It would be better to replace your intrinsic event handler attributes with [programatic event binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: That is really weird. It works when i run it in JSFiddle, but not when i run it locally..
Any idea on why that could be?

Comment: No. I can't see your local code. The JavaScript console in your browser might have some useful error messages though.

Comment: The code is exactly the same, which is why it's so weird.
Except for the part, that i load the JS as an external file..

Comment: Chrome gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", when i type something in the input form.
Its very strange..

Comment: Presumably, then, the code is not the same. The script is in a different place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Thanks for the link!
Moving the script's "link" to the bottom of the body fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using this :

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" id="cathetusA" onkeyup=calculate();>
```

If you are using the same id with every form things  your code will not work.
Id must be unique for every object

Comment: why you say so? where you see duplicate?

Comment: "This is how all the forms are set up: <input type="number" step="0.01" id="cathetusA" onkeyup=calculate();>

" how all the forms

Comment: They're all set up that way, but with different ID's.
Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I have added all the code (HTML, CSS and JS) to the fiddle, so it's easier to look/test the code.